# MVC4 - NullReferenceException being thrown in view when trying to use a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, nullreferenceexception

On my home (index) page I have two partials, one renders a search form and the other results from the search:

```
<div class="row-fluid well">
    <div class="span6">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_BasicPropertySearchPartial.cshtml")
    </div>
    <div class="span6" id="basic-property-search-results">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_BasicPropertySearchResultsPartial.cshtml")
    </div>
</div>
```

In my `SearchController` a GET action returns the search form:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BasicPropertySearch()
{
    return PartialView("_BasicPropertySearchPartial");
}
```

And a POST action gets user input from the form and returns results based on a query:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BasicPropertySearch(BasicPropertySearchViewModel viewModel)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ResidentialProperty>();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using(var db = new LetLordContext())
        {
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.HasBackGarden);
            //...
            var results = db.ResidentialProperty.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();

            GenericSearchResultsViewModel<ResidentialProperty> gsvm = 
                    new GenericSearchResultsViewModel<ResidentialProperty> { SearchResults = results };

            return PartialView("_BasicPropertySearchResultsPartial", gsvm);
        }            
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong...");
    return View("_BasicPropertySearchPartial");
}
```

I've created a generic view model because search results may be lists of different types:

```
public class GenericSearchResultsViewModel<T>
{
    public List<T> SearchResults { get; set; }

    public GenericSearchResultsViewModel()
    {
        this.SearchResults = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

The POST action returns the following view:

```
@model LetLord.ViewModels.GenericSearchResultsViewModel<LetLord.Models.ResidentialProperty>

@if (Model.SearchResults == null) // NullReferenceException here!
{
    <p>No results in list...</p>
}
else
{
    foreach (var result in Model.SearchResults)
    {
    <div>
        @result.Address.Line1
    </div>
    }
}
```

I've put breakpoints on the GET and POST actions and the exception is being thrown before either or hit.

Is this problem being caused because `index.cshtml` is being rendered before it has a chance to do the GET/POST in the `SearchController`?

If so, does this mean it's a routing problem?

Finally, I thought `new`ing `SearchResults` in the constructor would overcome `NullReferenceExceptions`?

Feedback appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the whole ``Model`` is null. If the ``ModelState.IsValid`` property returns false in your postback action, you are returning a view without a model. Might that be the problem?

Comment: As per my question, I've a breakpoint on both actions and neither are being hit so I don't think it's that. Maybe I need to check in Index.cshtml is the list null before rendering the search results...?

Comment: If you are getting a ``NullReferenceException`` at the statement ``Model.SearchResults``, the Model must be null. If you can confirm that in the debugger, you should set breakpoints on every return statement (``return View(...)``) to get a clue which one forces the view to render. Your Index view is returned anywhere else, not in one of the actions you posted above. What's the name of the partial view causing the exception? Is it rendered through your ``Html.Partial`` calls? They lack a model, too.

Comment: Okay you've got me thinking. Index action is in the HomeController, and it isn't returning anything, just `return View()` (which contains the first code segmant from the question). The partial that's causing the exception is `BasicPropertySearchResultsPartial`. So do you think Index is rendering that partial before it gets a chance to call the actions from the `SearchController`?

Comment: The child actions are not called at all through your Index action. For using child actions (which then can return a partial view) you need to use ``Html.Action`` not ``Html.Partial``.

Comment: Tried that, but I'm getting an exception: `{"A public action method '~/Views/Search/_BasicPropertySearchPartial.cshtml' was not found on controller 'LetLord.Controllers.HomeController}`. This is because those actions are in the `SearchController`. Should I make what I currently have in my Index.cshtml into a partial, and get Index action to return PartialView instead of just a Partial?

Comment: You will need to specify an action and a controller as arguments to ``Html.Action`` as you can see in the msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise `Html.Action` took controllerAction/controllerName string parameters. This seems to be working now, thanks. If you'd like to sum up your comments in an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the whole `Model` is null. You need to either supply a partial view model to the `Html.Partial` calls or use `Html.Action` to call the two controller (child) actions with the action and controller names.

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for details.